# Using OleDB to update an Excel Sheet

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello and happy holidays!


I am trying to import an excel sheet (containing multiline cells) into a DataGridView control. Then I apply changes inside the DataGridView control, and the objective is to successfully update the excel sheet.

Here are my declarations first:

```
Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Test Folder\Sample.xlsx"
Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim oAdapater As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim oDataTable As New DataTable
```

First, I open the excel sheet (with 200 columns and 200 rows filled out) and populate it:

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
     Try
        oConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""")
        oAdapater = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", oConnection)
        oConnection.Open()
        oAdapater.Fill(oDataTable)
        oConnection.Close()

        'Setting my Key Column
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KeyTest"))
        Dim primaryKey(1) As DataColumn
        primaryKey(1) = oDataTable.Columns("KeyTest")
        oDataTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKey



        DataGridView1.DataSource = oDataTable
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occured")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then, I attempt to update the sheet:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim TestCB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(oAdapater)
    oAdapater.UpdateCommand = TestCB.GetUpdateCommand
    oAdapater.Update(oDataTable)
End Sub
```

This is where I am getting stuck:

When I click on btnUpdate entries, I get this error:

> **InvalidOperationException was unhandled**
> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   
>  Additional information: Dynamic SQL generation for the
>   UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not
>   return any key column information.

So, my research on Google suggests that this isn't going to work because I am using an Excel file which does not contain Keys. Any recommendations on what alternative I can use that does contain keys? Basically the information I'm trying to store is a combination of multi-line letters and numbers across about 20 columns and about 200 rows.

Comment: One major misconception: the first snippet puts the data into a `DataTable` which is merely *viewed* in a DataGridView.  Moving the data from the DGV to an array is pure needless overhead when you could use it from the DataTable

Comment: @Plutonix Oh, I didn't know that! That's actually really great to know, thanks! :)

Comment: @Plutonix I just read online that moving data from a DataTable won't maintain formatting (no special fonts or colors here, just strings on different lines within a single grid). Is this true? If so, I'd have to use the DGV, no?

Comment: Your site has it backwards.  The DataTable will have the data as it was in the XL file, the DGV may display it differently though.  Depending on the data you are working with, it is possible that `myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)` using a fully configured Adapter will write the data back to the XLS with no other heroics.  it depends on whether there is a key column with unique values or not.

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you! There's definitely a key column :(. I'll do some more digging and see what I can find. I really appreciate you pointing my in the right direction - this is all very confusing.

Comment: Its also dependent on whether OleDB *recognizes* the column as such, but you should be able to do basic SQL updates

Comment: @Plutonix Haha, thanks! Unfortunately I know only very basic coding so whatever you just said is wayyy beyond me!

Comment: @Plutonix Hey, thanks again for the help yesterday - can you see if I'm on the right track? I've updated.

Comment: Ummm, kinda. The DA should be the same one you used to read the file, make it a form level variable; that code is trying to use a SQL SELECT for an UPDATE .  Then you need to use the command builder.  It will build the UPDATE statement for you.  If OleDB cant work out the unique column you can try specifying Primary Key columns.  Even if that cant work, you can use the RowState in the DataTable to know what to update manually.

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you! I've cleaned up the original post and added my full code. I think that I misunderstood you before - no, I don't have a key column designated. Do I need to? As far as using the command builder to build the UPDATE statement for me and then to subsequently update the sheet...Is there any way I can convince you to give me a short sample? please?

Comment: All things considered, it would probably be easier to fill a DT, use it as a DS, then loop thru **that** and evaluate the RowState to issue the appropriate SQL statement.  I have no idea what the data looks like to know what or if Keys would help.

Comment: @Plutonix Okay - As you recommended, I have created a DataTable (original post updated) and am using it as a DS. Could you give me an example, or just a link will suffice (because I can't seem to find any) of the loop that you're talking about?

Comment: Can the user update any and all the columns, or is there one or two that must remain the same?  If they can change any of them, it wont work because you wont be able to specify which row to update. Deleting rows brings up more issues.   Another alternative would be to write out a CSV that they can import.  This all points out what a terrible idea it is to use Excel as if it is a database, because it isnt.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, the user can update any and all columns. So I see that there is an issue. Is there a different database that you would recommend? I need to be able to add multiline cells.

Comment: SQLite, Access or the personal/compact version of SQL Server should work

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you! Could you just write something - anything - so I can mark something as an answer?